# Definition of q congruent to 1 (mod p)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the meaning of q $\equiv 1\pmod p$?

If I were to write this as a definition, how would I explain with this means?

Comment: $a\equiv b\pmod c$ means that $c$ is a divisor of $a-b$.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning is that $p$ divides $q$ with remainder $1$.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to clarify in the original question, but I was supposed to write the meaning of it in terms of divisibility. But, it seems like you did just that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the simplest way to phrase it would be:

If you subtract 1 from q, you get a multiple of p.

Answer (score 0):

It means $p$ divides $q-1$.

$$q \equiv 1 \mod p$$

$$\implies q-1 \equiv 0 \mod p$$

$$\implies p | (q-1) $$

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and steps!